# Memoized recursive functions. How to make them fool-proof?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Memoized functions are functions which remember values they have found.
Look in the doc center for some background on this in Mathematica, if necessary.

Suppose you have the following definition

```
f[0] = f[1] = 1
f[x_] := f[x] = f[x - 1] + f[x - 2]
```

in one of your packages. A user may load the package and start asking right away f[1000].
This will trigger a $RecursionLimit::reclim error message and abort.
Even if the user then tries something smaller, say f[20], by now the definition of f is corrupt and the result is not good anymore.Of course the package developer might increase the recursion limit and warn the user, but my question is:

How can you improve the f definition so that if the user asks for f[1000] he/she gets the answer without any problem? I am interested in a way to trap the user input, analyze it and take whatever steps are necessary to evaluate f[1000].

I can easily imagine that one can change the recursion limit if the input is more than 255 (and then bring it back to the original level), but what I would really like to see is, if there is a way for the f to find out how many values it "knows" (fknownvalues) and accept any input <=fknownvalues+$RecursionLimit without problems or increase the $RecursionLimit if the input is higher.

Thank you for your help

Comment: That looks tricky in the general case, especially if you have more than one parameter, and the recursion does not strictly decrease them in each step.

Comment: @Thilo If it weren't tricky I would not have asked it :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the code assuming that you can determine a value of `$RecursionLimit` from the value of the input argument:

```
Clear[f];
Module[{ff},
  ff[0] = ff[1] = 1;
  ff[x_] := ff[x] = ff[x - 1] + ff[x - 2];

  f[x_Integer] :=f[x] =
     Block[{$RecursionLimit = x + 5},
        ff[x]
  ]]
```

I am using a local function `ff` to do the main work, while `f` just calls it wrapped in `Block` with a proper value for `$RecursionLimit`:

```
In[1552]:= f[1000]
Out[1552]=  7033036771142281582183525487718354977018126983635873274260490508715453711819693357974224
9494562611733487750449241765991088186363265450223647106012053374121273867339111198139373125
598767690091902245245323403501
```

**EDIT**

If you want to be more precise with the setting of `$RecursionLimit`, you can modify the part of the code above as:

```
f[x_Integer] :=
  f[x] =
    Block[{$RecursionLimit = x - Length[DownValues[ff]] + 10},
    Print["Current $RecursionLimit: ", $RecursionLimit];
    ff[x]]]
```

The `Print` statement is here for illustration. The value `10` is rather arbitrary - to get a lower bound on it, one has to compute the necessary depth of recursion, and take into account that the number of known results is `Length[DownValues[ff]] - 2` (since `ff` has 2 general definitions). Here is some usage:

```
In[1567]:= f[500]//Short

During evaluation of In[1567]:= Current $RecursionLimit: 507
Out[1567]//Short= 22559151616193633087251269<<53>>83405015987052796968498626

In[1568]:= f[800]//Short

During evaluation of In[1568]:= Current $RecursionLimit: 308
Out[1568]//Short= 11210238130165701975392213<<116>>44406006693244742562963426
```

If you also want to limit the maximal `$RecursionLimit` possible, this is also easy to do, along the same lines. Here, for example, we will limit it to 10000 (again, this goes inside `Module`):

```
f::tooLarge = 
"The parameter value `1` is too large for single recursive step. \
Try building the result incrementally";
f[x_Integer] :=
   With[{reclim = x - Length[DownValues[ff]] + 10},
     (f[x] =
        Block[{$RecursionLimit = reclim },
        Print["Current $RecursionLimit: ", $RecursionLimit];
        ff[x]]) /; reclim < 10000];

f[x_Integer] := "" /; Message[f::tooLarge, x]]
```

For example:

```
In[1581]:= f[11000]//Short

During evaluation of In[1581]:= f::tooLarge: The parameter value 11000 is too 
large for single recursive step. Try building the result incrementally
Out[1581]//Short= f[11000]

In[1582]:= 
f[9000];
f[11000]//Short

During evaluation of In[1582]:= Current $RecursionLimit: 9007
During evaluation of In[1582]:= Current $RecursionLimit: 2008
Out[1583]//Short= 5291092912053548874786829<<2248>>91481844337702018068766626
```

Comment: That is the part that @magma could "easily imagine". Would be nice if there was a way to figure out how far $RecursionLimit really needs to be raised considering that there are already some memoized values.

Comment: @Thilo Please see my edit - based on magma's suggestion (assuming recursion depth as `input - number-of-known-results + const`. If it still exceeds that, my last code has a limit which would tell the user that the computation must be split into several steps.

Comment: Since `$RecursionLimit` is only set locally for this function, why not set it to `Infinity` in the `Block` instead of trying to come up with a "big enough" value?  The safety problem still remains in any case: have a too deep recursion, and the kernel will crash.  I am not aware of any way to determine the largest crash-safe `$RecursionLimit`, if anyone knows one, let me know.

Comment: @Thilo I would say that recursion can be defined on a restricted class of parzially ordered sets (posets) of inputs. Can't remember its exact name right now. The fact that you have more than one parameter (ie. you work on a cartesian product of suitable posets) is not a problem, since you can use (for example ) lexicographic ordering. Any reasonably defined recursive function must by necessity "decrease" the parameter in each step

Comment: This is an excellent answer! The trick I was looking for was Length[DownValues[..]]. Obvious in retrospect. Silly me :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs I guess there is no single universal limiting "safe" value for `$RecursionLimit`, since it must be determined by the memory used by the stack, which depends on the problem. My experiments resulted in crashes for `$RecursionLimit` in the range of hundreds thousands. It probably should be possible to have an estimate on the available stack space, although this won't help much. Regardless, I would *never* use `$RecursionLimit = Infinity`, since this is a true recipe for disaster. If possible, one should use tail-recursive (in mma sense) functions to reduce recursion to iteration.

Comment: @magma  Note that for a large (tens of thousands or more) number of definitions, `DownValues[f]`  may take considerable time to execute. If such cases will be frequent, you may want to keep a separate counter (localized inside the same `Module`), which is incremented every time when a new definition is added, to reduce the overhead.

Comment: One comment and 2 questions. 1 The 10 in the recursionlimit formulae should be at least 20, to avoid $RecursionLimit::limset error, as hinted by @belisarius answer below.2 This Module wrapper trick is shown also in the module page of the doc center, applications section. What is its advantage vs using a direct f definition? 3 why is the x localized in the Module? (Look at the ??f info)

Comment: A localized separate counter updated each time a definition is added, was my original idea. Your Length[DownValues[..]] is more elegant, with all its speed limitations.

Comment: @magma Regarding 20 instead of 10 - good point, I forgot about limset.The `Module` trick is necessary here to keep memoized definitions. If you only use `f`, then I don't see an easy way to have both the main memoized definition `f[x_] := f[x] = f[x - 1] + f[x - 2]` *and* the one that is checking a recursion limit. Perhaps, one can do it, I just found it easier to delegate memoization to another symbol. Regarding `x$` - it is not lolalized in `Module` despite its look, but is a result of `SetDelayed` renaming its pattern variable inside `Module`, to avoid name possible name collisions.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry if my previous comment was re-iterating the obvious. My main message was that I do agree with your main point - the safety problem remains. I just wish we were given more information about the stack use from the system. I actually tried to measure things like `ByteCount[Stack[]]` or `LeafCount[Stack[]]` in my experiments, to see if some univeral limits on these can be found, but did not succeed.

Answer (score 6):

A slight modification on Leonid's code. I guess I should post it as a comment, but the lack of comment formatting makes it impossible.

Self adaptive Recursion Limit

```
Clear[f];
$RecursionLimit = 20;
Module[{ff},
 ff[0] = ff[1] = 1;
 ff[x_] := 
  ff[x] = Block[{$RecursionLimit = $RecursionLimit + 2},  ff[x - 1] + ff[x - 2]];
 f[x_Integer] := f[x] = ff[x]]

f[30]
(*
-> 1346269
*)

$RecursionLimit
(*
-> 20
*)
```

**Edit**

Trying to set $RecursionLimit sparsely:

```
Clear[f];
$RecursionLimit = 20;
Module[{ff}, ff[0] = ff[1] = 1;
 ff[x_] := ff[x] =
   Block[{$RecursionLimit =
      If[Length@Stack[] > $RecursionLimit - 5, $RecursionLimit + 5, $RecursionLimit]}, 
       ff[x - 1] + ff[x - 2]];
 f[x_Integer] := f[x] = ff[x]]
```

Not sure how useful it is ...

Comment: +1. I was thinking of adding something similar to my answer, but you did it first and perhaps more elegantly than what I intended to do. One may want increase the `$RecursionLimit` step if the overhead of increasing in small steps is too much.

Comment: @Leonid I guess a coarser step control would require incrementing a variable, or at least meassuring the stack depth.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. I did not give this suggestion much thought, it may be harder to implement well.

Comment: This is also a very interesting solution, which uses Block inside Block recursion